# Eclipse HANGS when Debug Perspective is Shown

Tags: android, eclipse, perspective

Eclipse hangs when I open the Debug Perspective.

I thought Eclipse was hanging when my app hit a breakpoint...but it turns out that Eclipse hangs when the debug perspective is shown.

I can reproduce the hang by opening Eclipse, then clicking Window/Open Perspective/Debug

Eclipse 3.7.2, running on Ubuntu 12.x

Help! :)

Comment: Stack trace if any ? logs ? It's hard to help you when we have nothing to go on.

Answer (score 2):

Today I run into the same problem with Eclipse 4.3 (Kepler) and found a solution how to fix it after doing some research. It might be too late for your problem, but I hope it helps others to fix the problem.

**These steps helped my to solve the issue**

1. Within your original workspace open `Window / Preferences / General / Perspectives`. Click on `Debug` Perspective within this window and click on `Revert`
2. Start your Eclipse with a new workspace.
3. Open the `Debug` perspective which freezes your Eclipse. In my case it was freezing in the original workspace, but it did not freeze in the new workspace.
4. Leave the `Debug` perspective open! Then close the new workspace and open the original workspace. In my case the `Debug` perspective did not freeze anymore and I could switch between all perspectives. However, some buttons did not had the right position, so I restarted the original workspace again. That fixed the perspective for me.

Best regards,
Michael

*PS: My problem occurred after I uninstalled PyDev to get a clean Android IDE (before that I mixed Android and Python in one IDE). PyDev is generating some UI elements in the debug perspective, which probably caused the issue.*